# Validate Required on Non Model MVC Dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a Dropdownlist from a Viewbag and I need to validate it like "Required"

My Controller

```
public ActionResult EsperaPorHora()
        {
            var cliente = new UsuarioData().Id_LicenciadoPorId(User.Identity.GetUserId());
            var Cli = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cliente.ToString()) ? Convert.ToInt32(cliente) : 0;
            var cliData = new LicenciadoData();
            var agora = DateTime.Now;
            ViewBag.Data1 = agora.ToShortDateString();
            ViewBag.Data2 = agora.ToShortDateString();

            if (Cli != 0)
            {
                ViewBag.IdCliente = new SelectList(cliData.ListaClienteId(Cli), "Id", "Fantasia");
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.IdCliente = new SelectList(cliData.ListarClientes(), "Id", "Fantasia");
            }           
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult EsperaHora(string data1, string data2, int? cliente)
        {
            var voiceData = new KiperVoiceData(cliente);
            var media = voiceData.GetEsperaData(data1, data2);
            var atend = voiceData.GetEsperaHora(data1, data2);

            var result = new { atend, media };
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

I tried:

```
@Html.DropDownList("IdCliente", null, "SELECIONE A EMPRESA", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control combo2", @required = "required" })                              

@Html.DropDownList("IdCliente", null, "SELECIONE A EMPRESA", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control combo2", @required = true })                              

@Html.DropDownList("IdCliente", null, "SELECIONE A EMPRESA", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control combo2", required = true })
```

But no one worked to me, if I click button without select it run to an exception. What im doing wrong?

Comment: You cannot get validation if your not binding to a model!. You need to bind to a model property (with a `[Required]` attribute, and the name of the `SelectList` cannot be the same as the name of the property your binding to. And then the parameter in the POST method need to be the model.

Comment: My dropdown is filled from a list, how i could bind it to a model? newbie here... Could i do a a js validation?

Comment: `@Html.DropDownListFor(m > m.PropertyToBindTo, Model.YouSelectList, "SELECIONE A EMPRESA", new { @class = "form-control combo2" })`

Comment: @RogerioAzevedo See my updated answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send the required as a class like this:

**Update**

Use an overload with optionlabel. I am passing "choose" here, but you can pass whatever you need. Also put a validation summary to inform the user it is a required field.

```
@Html.ValidationSummary()
 @Html.DropDownList("name", new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem { Text = "1", Value = "2" } }, "choose", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control combo2 required", @data_val = "true", @data_val_required = "choose is a required field" })
```

Comment: I tried as you suggested but, it's not worked, if I click button to POST, it run to an exception because the variable is NULL, I thinking the best solution to me is validating null on JS. I will try and will tell you later.

Comment: It does work. Copy and Paste my code and you will see it works. You code is diffdrent I think.

Comment: I just copied and paste it on my project and i think it will work, with your dropdown it not ran to an exception. I will try to get the selectlist from my viewbag and create the validation. Thank you! Did you see the solution i found?

Answer (score 0):

Solve the situation on html and razor is important, primarily to improve my knowledge. As I told above, I could find a solution using Js and a component named Sweet Alert as follow:

```
var data1 = $('#data1').val();
var data2 = $('#data2').val();
var cliente = $('#IdCliente option:selected').val();

if (cliente != "") {

            $.ajax({
                url: '',
                dataType: "json",
                type: "GET",
                data: { 'data1': data1, 'data2': data2, 'cliente': cliente },
                success: function (data) {
                    }
                },

                error: function (xhr) {
                    alert('error');
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            swal({ type: "warning", title: "Alerta", text: "Selecione uma empresa por favor!", timer: 5000, showConfirmButton: true });
        }
```

This is the result:

[image: Alert Sweet]

Comment: This solution is fine but in the web world this is rarely done. In the web world the error is shown beside the required field and/or a summary is shown at the top of the form. For example, on stackoverlow, gmail and most other sites when you are logging in if you do not fill in the fields during logging in or creating an account, it will not show you a dialog. Also, if your site is visited from a smartphone, it will be even more awkward to see an alert.